# Refresh parent page before popup page closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to refresh my parent page before closing popup page automatically, Something like close Asp:button on popup page & on click of close button my parent page should be refresh...
using jquery/js any solution plz...!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `window.opener.reload()` for your onClick handler

Comment: You mean something like below?  umm bt not working below function... in popout window i wrote this >>>function popInWindow() {
            
            window.opener.reload();
            alert("Width"+vWidth+"Window is now pop-in");
            window.close();

Comment: For the close button that closes the popup write `onclick="window.opener.reload();window.close();"`